# How to limit the number of jobs on a host using Sungrid?

Tags: sungridengine

I am using Sungrid6.2u5 ,I am trying to submit some jobs on 4 hosts, I need to run 50 jobs using all the 4 hosts but I want to inform the SGE that I want only 5 jobs to be run on the 4th host at any given time,how do I do that?

I am new to SunGrid.Could any one please point me to the SGE basics,I mean where do I get started?
I found this online,

***Beginner's Guide to Sun Grid Engine 6.2 by Daniel Templeton***
but apparently this is intended for system administrators ,I am just a normal user who is trying to understand the SGE features.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you should not run more than 5 jobs on 4th node **(let's call it `computer04`)**, probably, it is not capable of running something more. In general, you are encouraged to specify amount of resources for you job properly to prevent cores overload and out-of-memory situation.

If you have totally 20 Gb on `computer04` and your job uses 5 Gb, you can limit all your jobs to `5Gb` memory usage:

`qsub -l vmem=5G my_work`

The similar holds for disk amount:

`qsub -l fsize=10G my_work`

I found it is possible to run job on specific host with `-l -h=` option.

```
qsub -l -h=computer04 -l vmem=5G my_work
```

for 5 jobs. Then use

```
qsub -l vmem=5G my_work
```

for other 45 jobs.

---

***(More dirty way)***
You could do it without memory/disk restrictions:

```
qsub -l -h=computer04 my_work # 5 jobs
qsub -l -h="!computer04" my_work # for 45 jobs
```

---

If you have different queues or resources, and you could use them for different jobs. E.g., you have `queue_4` that runs everything on `computer04`, and `queue_main` that is linked with other computers, then, you do

```
qsub -q queue_4 my_work
```

for 5 jobs, and

```
qsub -q queue_main my_work
```

for other jobs.

---

UPD on comment:

It is possible to force SGE denial of more than `X` jobs for user/host. It should be done by queue administrator.

```
qconf -arqs  
{
   name         max_jobs_per_computer04
   description  "maximal number of jobs for user1 on computer04 restricted to 5!"
   enabled      TRUE
   limit        users user1 hosts computer04 to slots=5
}
```

If you want to restrict your user only in submitting jobs of ***some kind*** for `computer04`, you need to define `complex parameter` as shown [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/byun/entry/limiting_archiving_jobs_on_sge).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I don't have multiple queues ,there is only one  queue with 4 hosts. I am looking for some kind of a switch or something through which I can limit the number of jobs to 5 on the 4th host while using the other three hosts to their maximum potential.Is it possible?

Comment: Use `qsub -l -h=computer04 my_work` for 5 jobs and `qsub -l -h="!computer04"` for other 46. But I suggest adding `vmem` or other resource specification to occupy the host totally, because without it anyone would still be able to submit jobs to 4th host.

Comment: But I have no way to separate these jobs, I have a list of jobs to be run and a perl script which takes that list as the input and invokes qsub. I cannot invoke qsub twice with the same list or can I? I am worried that the same job will be executed on two different machines.

Comment: How does `perl` invoke `qsub`? Does it use a loop? Then use `conditional` operator with the value of looping variable. `if ($i < 6) {..specific qsub...} else {...usual qsub...}`

Comment: I use backticks in the Perl  script to set the necessary environmental variables and to invoke the qsub . In reality I may have to run 1000 jobs but I still want to control the number of jobs on the 4th host .As you suggested ,I can take care of that in the script,I can submit every 10th job on the 4th host and rest of them on remaining three hosts but I am wondering if there is any way I can achieve this using some qsub switch . Can't I control the number of jobs on one host? I am aware that I can specify the maximum number of jobs but they get distributed among all the four hosts.

Comment: Thanks a lot John,it was really helpful,appreciate your time.